# Creating subfolder in Eclipse with folders listed in one line

Tags: eclipse

I created a new webapp project in Maven and noticed that the Java folder was not being created.

So, I created a new folder under src/main/java..The folders are listed in a nested format

ie;

```
src
   main 
       java
```

When I noticed few other existing projects, I noticed its in the following structure

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
```

What option needs to be enabled to change the setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package Explorer / View Menu (Ctrl-F10) / Package Presentation... / Hierarchical

Comment: He's not talking about packages, but directories, as far as I understood the question.

Comment: The problem was I was in a Pydev prespective..ONce I changed to Java, I got the correct version

Answer (score -1):

If you have the Maven Eclipse plugin, right click on the project and select **Maven > Update Project Configuration**. Then the source folders are selected and you have the flat structure within your Eclipse project like **src/main/java**.

Another way (without Maven plugin): Right click on the corresponding src directory and select **Build Path > Use as Source Folder**